# Before save event for Excel added on to what I already have to check again

Tags: excel

I want the code that I have already to do a before save event that checks to see if column E is clear and clears content I have in Column A. The code I have clears the cells in column A already I want it to check and clear other rows if the cell in Column E is cleared before saving.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Column = 5 Then
      If Target.Value = vbEmpty Then
         Cells(Target.Row, 1).ClearContents
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```